# How can I read a line of text from a file without skipping a blank line?

Tags: c++, file, stream

I have some input file that looks like this:

```
asdfasfasfas....

asdfasdfasd....
asdfasdf....

asdfsadf...
```

I want to be able to read line by line the whole line, without skipping the blank lines in between. How can I do this? Each line has no white space in it, but if I simply read in and process as:

```
 std::string line;
 file >> line;
 Foo(line);
```

Then it skips the second line and jumps straight to the second. I don't want that to happen. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getline` to read line by line, rather than `operator>>` that will skip the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

This reads every line, one at a time, until the end of the file, and displays them on the screen.

By default, `std::istream::operator>>` does *formatted input*, which (amongst other things) means all whitespace is dropped.  For whitespace of any sort (including newlines), you need *unformatted input*.  `get`, `read`, `getline`, and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

you may also read character by character till the end of the line andstore it in an array and then move the file pointer to the next line and so on..